# How do ISPs detect whether a phone uses tethering?

Tags: network, mobile

I'm trying to figure out how ISPs detect whether a phone uses tethering beyond checking whether the TTL is set to a particular value. Also, do any major ISPs use a form of passive traffic fingerprinting?

Comment: How is this related to information security?

Comment: Well, Telecom companies use a wide variety of detection techniques to detect tethering and I'm trying to figure out how it's being detected.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to ask "How do ISPs detect whether a phone uses tethering?", because everything you presented so far seems off-topic to me.

Comment: I'm looking to apply that knowledge to my particular situation. Is there a particular way I can ask for such information that applies to my specific situation?

Comment: We don't do tech support, we answer questions. What you can do is do your own research as far as possible, and then ask a question that will help you solve the problem on your own. Merely describing a situation and asking "Can someone help me?" [is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Ah, thank you for answering my questions.

Comment: You're welcome. It's an interesting question, so if it doesn't get an answer in the next days, I'll add a bounty to it.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to figure out how ISPs detect whether a phone uses tethering beyond checking whether the TTL is set to a particular value.

There is a good description about various ways over at android.stackexchange.com - [How can phone companies detect tethering (incl. Wifi hotspot)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47819/how-can-phone-companies-detect-tethering-incl-wifi-hotspot). No need to repeat it all here but apart from TTL and OS stack fingerprinting it is also about the tethering feature of the phone actually telling the mobile ISP that tethering is active. For the latter aspect see also [this post at Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20460438) where it states that another DUN is used for tethering and how to avoid this.

Very interesting is also an article from Sandvine [Policy Control for Connected and Tethered Devices](https://www.sandvine.com/hubfs/downloads/archive/technology-showcase-policy-control-for-connected-and-tethered-devices.pdf) since Sandvine is actually a provider for the necessary technology. In this articles it mentions features like TCP timestamp option, behavior of TCP source port, number of parallel sessions, various features from the HTTP request etc to distinguish different devices.

Similar Cisco offers tethering detection in its products as can be seen from [ECS Administration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/asr_5000/21/ECS/21-ECS-Admin/21-ECS-Admin_chapter_01110.html). Here it again mentions TTL but also OS fingerprinting and User-Agent detection.

> Also, do any major ISPs use a form of passive traffic fingerprinting?

This is very common. If an ISP offers pricing models where specific traffic (like some music or video streaming) is excluded from the accounted bandwidth then you know for sure that deep packet inspection is used. Apart from that it might be used to block or disrupt services which impact the business model or terms of service, like using VoIP or P2P file sharing or tethering. Sometimes it is done for legal reasons like blocking access to specific domains. But it might also be done to actually enhance the service, i.e. prioritize real time traffic against other traffic.